# Proper way to toggle classes in Ember Octane with Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, frontend, ember-octane

I want to toggle between class display on and display-off using Ember.js Octane.  How do I do this?  Do I need an @action or @tracked?

```
<img src="flower.jpg" alt="flower" class="display-on">  
or
<img src="flower.jpg" alt="flower" class="display-off">
```

Comment: What changes in deciding which of these two classes to use? Is there something the user clicks? Or some information that you know when the page loads?

Answer (score 5):

This should be straight-forward in Ember (especially with Octane features).

As mentioned by @jrjohnson in the comment, the markup depends on how you manage the way you track the state, by which the classes are toggled. In an ideal case, since you need to toggle the `class` alone, you can render the class using the conditionals in the template with the help of a JS Class property, `canShow`:

```html
<img src="flower.jpg" alt="flower" class={{if this.canShow "display-on" "display-off"}}>
```

here, `canShow` has to be [@tracked](https://octane-guides-preview.emberjs.com/release/state-management/tracked-properties/) (as you mentioned) if you need to re-render the view(template) when it's value changes.

Hope you having fun learning Ember ;)

Comment: I submitted an edit showing the button and action, but in the meantime, here's the content:

`<button {{on "click" this.toggleImage}}>Toggle</button>`

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class MyComponentComponent extends Component {
  @tracked canShow = true;

  @action
  toggleImage() {
    this.canShow = !this.canShow
  }
}
```

Comment: @handlebears, I think you are better off making a separate reply with your suggestions..